# Creating Tags case insensitive rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, tagging

I have a Tag model that

`has validates_uniqueness_of :name, :case_sensitive => false`

and then I have a before_filter 
that creates these tags for a post

`Tag.find_or_create_by_name(name)`

When I create a post and then assign the tag "Toy" it creates it successfully, I then do a new post and add the tag "toy" and get this `Validation failed: Name has already been taken`. How should I make it so that "Toy" and "toy" are still the same tag?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Store all tags in downcase and find tags in downcase

```
Tag.find_or_or_create_by_name(name.downcase)
```

To find it anyway:

```
Tag.where("LOWER(name) = ?", name.downcase)
```

Comment: +1, and then you can @tag.name.capitalize to get it back to the current form.

Comment: Thanks I forgot about .downcase